# Was Cyrus really Queen Esther's son?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, historical-figures, esther--the-woman

Are there any Talmudic sources that back up the claim that Cyrus was really the son of Queen Esther?

Comment: First of all, I assume you mean Cyrus II, aka Darius II. I believe there is a source, not sure where; but I also heard a midrash that an angel appeared in the form of esther and gave birth to him.

Comment: Who makes the claim?

Comment: Was this claim made as Midrash or History? The two are often not the same.

Comment: @user613 I see no evidence that [Darius II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_II) was also called Cyrus II.

Comment: At least according to the Zohar, King Darius _wasn't_ Queen Esther's son: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13123/11486

Answer (score 4):

The Gemara in Rosh Hashana 3b(which talks about when to start the counting of a kings reign) writes that Koresh(he was a kosher king),Daryavesh(his actual name),and Artachasasta(name of his kingdom) are one in the same.

The question is was Daryavish Esther's son. The simple answer is that its a machlokes. Tosfos on that Daf explains that Daryavish was Eshter's son based of the Midrash Va'yikra Rabah 13:5. However, Rashi holds on 4a that Daryavish was a ben noach, seemingly Rashi did not go with the opinion of the midrash.

Comment: Some Rishonim take that whole Gemara as non-literal, fwiw.

Comment: Good answer. Just pointing out, the gemara says he went bad later (I think the one you referenced). But that's not a problem with the answer

Answer (score 1):

Rashi says that Cyrus was the son of Esther. I have a source at home, I'll have to dig it up.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kalla Rabbasi 2:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40939&st=%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8&pgnum=61&hilite=) seems to indicate this.

> מה בנה של אסתר כתיב (ישעיה מה) אני לפניך אלך והדורים אישר דלתות נחושה אשבר ובריחי
>   ברזל אגדע...

Answer (score -2):

Don't know if you mean Cyrus 1 or 2 (just found out from another commenter that there was more than one), but at least one seems to have preceded the megillah:
http://www.chabad.org/holidays/in-depth/default_cdo/aid/39643/jewish/Megillah-with-Commentary.htm
And it came to pass in the days of Achashverosh (Esther 1:1)
Achashverosh succeeded Cyrus as ruler of the Persian Empire, toward the end of the Jews' seventy-year exile in Babylon (Rashi)

Comment: The answer does not seem to apply to the question

Comment: So it [appears that the question is about Darius II](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/was-cyrus-really-queen-esthers-son#comment170021_61936)

Comment: That was Cyrus I