# Can demons have kids with humans?

Tags: sheidim-demons

I heard that some rishonim of blessed memory said demons can have intercourse with humans. So could demons have kids with humans?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13123/759

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question would be a great deal more compelling if you'd [edit] in more detail about where you heard about rishonim discussing demon/human intercourse and, if possible, which rishonim were cited.

Comment: this seems like a question for https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The mekubalim say that the reason it was customary in Yerushalayim for women to not attend funerals is that the person dying would make a cherem on his daughters from attending his funeral, intending to include his physical daughters and also his demonic daughters that he had created through intimacy with Lillis (through being motzei zerah le'vatalah etc.).

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly the implication of, say, Rashbam (to Bava Basra 73a) who writes that Hormin was born from a man who fornicated with a female demon. And the same is implied by the notion that Sichon and Og were born of the "fallen angels" who copulated with human women (as angels and demons seem to be similar sorts of creatures).

For more sources on this topic, see what I wrote at:

- http://www.hakirah.org/Vol26Klein.pdf (page 271, fn. 51)
- https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53279&st=&pgnum=161

Answer (score 1):

There's a Perek in Kav Hayshar that says a man (who cheated on his wife) would have relations with his Demon Mistress. But no kids were produced.

Comment: I'll find that Perek

Comment: It's in perek 25.

Comment: But anyways the original question asked about Rishonim, and Kav HaYashar is not a rishon.